# SUM() Returning Incorrect Values

Tags: mysql, sum

I have a few tables, products, incoming, and outgoing. Outgoing and incoming have two rows which gives some idea to whats going on because the results I get from the query are twice what they should be

```
SELECT products.ProductName, products.StartingInventory,
        sum(incoming.NumReceived) invReceived, sum(outgoing.NumberShipped) invShipped,
        products.InventoryOnHand, products.MinimumRequired 
from incoming, products, outgoing 
where incoming.ProductId = products.id and outgoing.ProductId = products.id 
group by products.id
```

The two values in question are invReceived and invShipped. This is the incoming table:

```
| id  SupplierID ProductID NumReceived PurchaseDate |
| 1   1          1         6           2018-02-01   |
| 2   1          1         7           2017-05-09   |
```

and the outgoing table

```
|id First    Middle    Last        ProductId NumberShipped OrderDate |
|1  Dan      Smith     Agent       1         6             2018-02-01|
|2  Bethany  Richards  Richardson  1         15            2018-04-20|
```

The result is invReceived: 26 and invShipped 36 but should be 13 and 18.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Using explicit JOINs is the standard, accepted style; implicit "comma" join notation has been out of favor for decades, as it is harder to read and maintain.

Comment: You are joining three tables.  So to see what is being summed look at `SELECT * from from incoming, products, outgoing where incoming.ProductId = products.id and outgoing.ProductId = products.id group by products.id`  What I think is that the join is making four rows: product 1 incoming 1 outgoing 1, product 1 incoming 1 outgoing 2, product 1 incoming 2 outgoing 1, and product 1 incoming 2 outgoing 2 which explains why everything is double.

Comment: When I do this, I get "SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'ivm.incoming.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause"

Comment: You need to calculate your sums by product first and only then join products with results.

Comment: Do you know an adequate statement to do this?

Comment: @Dan185 Use proper `JOIN`.  Use proper `GROUP BY`.  No wonder query is messed up.

Comment: What about `SELECT *,
(select sum(NumReceived) from incoming
where ProductId = products.id) NumReceived,
(select sum(NumberShipped) from outgoing
where ProductId = products.id) NumberShipped
from products;`

Comment: This works, thank you.

Comment: Please don’t post data/code as images. Post it as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the `group by` and aggregate functions (ie. `sum`) reveals the problem.

```
sqlite> SELECT products.ProductName, products.StartingInventory,
   ...>         incoming.NumReceived invReceived, outgoing.NumberShipped invShipped,
   ...>         products.InventoryOnHand, products.MinimumRequired 
   ...> from incoming, products, outgoing 
   ...> where incoming.ProductId = products.id and outgoing.ProductId = products.id 
   ...> 
   ...> ;
ProductName  StartingInventory  invReceived  invShipped  InventoryOnHand  MinimumRequired
-----------  -----------------  -----------  ----------  ---------------  ---------------
Dell         290                6            3           300              10             
Dell         290                7            3           300              10             
Dell         290                6            15          300              10             
Dell         290                7            15          300              10
```

(*I'm doing this in SQLite, but there should be no difference from MySQL.*)

Rows are being counted twice. We can see the problem clearer by just selecting the IDs.

```
sqlite> SELECT products.id, incoming.id, outgoing.id
   ...> from incoming, products, outgoing 
   ...> where incoming.ProductId = products.id and outgoing.ProductId = products.id 
   ...> ;
id          id          id        
----------  ----------  ----------
1           1           1         
1           2           1         
1           1           2         
1           2           2
```

---

There's several ways to solve this. [One is from @JerryJermiah in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51663109/sum-returning-incorrect-values#comment90290107_51663109).

```
SELECT products.id, 
    (select sum(incoming.NumReceived)
     from incoming
     where incoming.productid = products.id),
    (select sum(outgoing.NumberShipped)
     from outgoing
     where outgoing.productid = products.id)
from products;
```

This fetches each product once and then does a sub-select on each product to get the NumReceived and NumberShipped.

You can also do a similar thing, but doing a join on subqueries.

```
select p.id, ig.NumReceived, og.NumShipped
from products p
join (
    select productid, sum(NumReceived) as NumReceived
    from incoming
    group by productid
) as ig on p.id = ig.productid
join (
    select productid, sum(NumberShipped) as NumShipped
    from outgoing
    group by productid
) as og on p.id = og.productid
```

This *might* be faster because SQL will only have to perform three queries instead of two for each product. Or maybe SQL optimization will take care of it. You'll have to do benchmarking.